# tmux vim colorscheme background is not showing

Tags: vim, tmux

I have installed tmux but now text mode vim colorschemes do not fill the background colour properly. Here is how it looks with colorscheme xoria256 in the normal Ubuntu 14.10 terminal:

[image]

And here when I run it in the exact same terminal after tmux:

[image]

So as you can see the desktop is showing through anywhere where there is no text in vim. I have a 256 color terminal.

My .tmux.conf:

```
~ cat .tmux.conf
set -g mode-mouse on
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

and I have a 256 colour terminal:

```
~ tput colors
256
```

How do I get tmux to work properly with vim 256-colour colorschemes which work fine in the normal terminal?

Comment: In my experience, tmux behaves strangely when launched inside `gnome-terminal`. Try launching tmux with `TERM=xterm tmux` and see if it behaves differently. If `xterm` doesn't work, try `xterm-256color` or `xterm-color`.

Comment: @jw03 Sadly none of those options worked to fix it. Identical behaviour. Same behaviour if I run tmux inside terminator

Comment: In a shell inside tmux, what’s the value of `$TERM`? If it’s not `screen-256color`, try launching `vim` as `TERM=screen-256color vim`, then make sure no startup script sets `TERM` (or, if you need to do that to work around buggy software, make sure it checks the original value first).

Comment: @minitech: Bingo. I had xterm-256color whereas screen-256color fixes the problem. If you make this an answer I will accept it.

Comment: This worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15095377/96855

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens when `TERM` isn’t set to the correct `screen[-256color]` in Vim’s environment, usually by some shell startup script. If that is the case – for example, you have a

```
TERM=xterm-256color
```

, either remove it or make sure it checks the original value of `TERM` before changing it, e.g.

```
if [[ "$TERM" = xterm ]]; then
    TERM=xterm-256color
fi
```

Answer (score 8):

in your `.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

Answer (score 3):

Late comment, but I had looked through all the threads and couldn't resolve it until I did the following. All I had to do was add a second check of

```
if [[ $TERM == screen]]; then
    TERM=screen-256color
fi
```

in addition to the first conditional statement in my `.bashrc` file:

```
if [[ $TERM == xterm ]]; then
    TERM=xterm-256color
fi
```

I also had this in `.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

In my `.vimrc` file:

```
set term=screen-256color
```